# Where can I find azure IoT device messages?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have sent messages to Azure IoT Hub device called dev1, I could not see the messages in IoT Hub but, I can read the messages only when the client application is online when the sender is sending messages. Azure IoT Hub supports only online messaging and no offline messaging? If offline message support is there, where are these messages are stored, I couldn't see the messages in IoT Hub.

When I configure the custom endpoint as Blob storage, I can see messages are stored in blobs.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for reading the messages directly on IoT Hub portal UI. If that is the case, then one of the things which you can make sure about D2C Messages in IoT Hub portal (UI perspective) is looking at the Metrics chart (See below Images). For reading the actual payload you have to make use of [in-built Event Hub endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin#read-from-the-built-in-endpoint) or routing to other [supported endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-custom#endpoints-and-routing).(You have already mentioned in your scenario-Client/Sender applications, So I think you have already known this method of reading messages)

The Metrics chart atleast tells you that the messages are received in IoT Hub (UI), you can't read them on the Portal(UI).
[image: IoT Hub metrics Chart_1]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub is built on top of Event Hubs, and that's where your messages will be until you start reading them. They will be stored there for 1 day by default, although you can change that up to 7 days. For more information on retention, please read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, can we see those mesages in event hubs in azure portal?

Comment: You can't see the content of the messages in the portal. You can see the amount coming through (as shown in the other answer on this question). If you want a quick and easy way to read the events, you can use Visual Studio Code and use the Azure IoT Tools plugin to read the events as they come in.